# CP2102 using excess current

Tags: voltage-regulator, power-consumption

I am powering an off-grid ESP32 project from a 12v battery (12v because that's what the connected pump and solenoids use). The ESP32 is directly on PCB; I'm no longer using Dev Kits. I'm needing a regulator that brings the 12v down to 3v3 for the microprocessor, one that uses minimal current to conserve battery power. The 12v input may rise to over 14v as there's a solar panel involved with charging the lead acid battery, which affects my choice of regulator.

The data sheet for the LF33 (https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/389/lfxx-1849555.pdf) shows quiescent current 12mA or less (target < 1mA) but I'm seeing in the region of 20mA with or without components (such as the ESP32) downstream of it. Edit: the excess seems to be downstream of the regulator.

A **direct swap** on the **same** PCB with a DC-DC converter (https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/CUI-Inc/VXO7803-1000) reduces current down to 7mA, so it's clearly something up with how I'm using the regulator. But I can't figure it out. The relevant part of the schematic is:

[image: powerSupply]

Edit; added full schematic (though the ESP32 isn't placed on the PCB for this test board)
[image: fullSchematic]

Edit; the problem is downstream of the regulator, so I've updated the question title.

Comment: Your second link redirects to this [link](https://www.mouser.co.uk/Electronic-Components/). Is that the whole schematic?

Comment: How are you measuring the quiescent current of the device? How do you know it isn;t as the datasheet suggests?

Comment: 'Scope the power rails and make sure there isn't an oscillation happening somehwere.

Comment: @ElectronSurf it may be that Mouser is redirecting you if you're not in the same country as me? That's not the whole schematic, just the regulator section. The plot thickens.. it appears that the additional current is further down the line somewhere, but only when this regulator is used. The only other significant component I have down the line is a CP2102. RDTSC - Scoping the power lines doesn't show anything unruly. I wonder if the CP2102 isn't going into suspend properly.

Comment: @MCG my assumption was that all downstream components were off/not relevant but it appears that they are somehow contributing to draw (I can only point the finger at the CP2102), so my test of the board overall consumption was an unrealistic view of the quiescent.

Comment: You would need to completely disconnect all components on the output side (to ensure no load) then measure the current from the input side of the regulator

Comment: A linear regulator with 12v in will burn three times as much power as heat, as it provided at the 3v3 output.  You definitely want to use a switcher for this.  When you use a switcher, the input current will actually be a lot *less* than the output current, as the input power is simply the output power divided by the regulator efficiency.  Where are you measuring the current anyway?  What's going on with the LM317's, are you backfeeding those?  Your CP2102 appears to be missing a bypass capacitor, but it's early to be blaming it - how have you removed the ESP32 module from the loads?

Comment: @ChrisStratton You're right about the linear regulator; a switcher my first choice but higher on cost so I'm exploring alternatives. I'm measuring current between output of regulator and 3v3 line. The LM317s are a basic solar charge controller; limiting voltage to 13.8-14.0V (small 10W panel). Two in parallel on the schematic to give a second set of pads to experiment with other options. Short of pulling the CP2102 off the board, I can't see where my lost 20mA are going. It's the same on multiple PCBs. I've not placed the ESP32 on these boards yet; so all the IOs are also open circuit too.

Comment: @ChrisT - Hi, "*I've not placed the ESP32 on these boards yet; so all the IOs are also open circuit too.*" Argh! So the schematic (showing the ESP32 and its connections) doesn't represent the test case! :-( (I just had another question where I wrote an answer based on a schematic - and the test case then turned out to be different :-( ). Please edit the question & add that new info about the test case there. "*It's the same on multiple PCBs*" There are various ways to gather the measurements needed to solve your problem. One way would be to sacrifice a PCB & start cutting traces. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The answer was the CP2012 was not de-powering (going into suspend mode), and it was drawing about 20mA. I tried bypass capacitors, pull-down on VBUS and D-, pull-up on RSTb with no joy. Sometimes, just sometimes, it powered down; more often with the DC-DC converter regulator for some reason. As I only rarely need UART (debug mainly) I'll put a jumper in place to isolate the UART completely when on battery power. CP21xx devices can be made to run off the USB power only, so powering off the plugged-in cable is an option too.